# If $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ are right bounded (left bounded) in an ordered field $F$, then so is their union

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ are right bounded (left bounded) in $F$, then so
is
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k.$$

Comment: Does the question require to prove that LHS = RHS

Comment: What do you mean by this, Avinesh? (LHS = left-hand side etc, but there doesn't seem to be any)

Comment: Please feel free to edit the title if I haven't interpreted your question correctly, Avinesh.

Comment: @ Zev Chonoles. Its correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of this geometrically first. It is given that $A_1$ is right bounded, so it lies to the left of some value, $k_1$. Similarly, $A_2$ lies to the left of some value $k_2$ and so on, but for the sake of intuition suppose there are only three sets (so the case $n=3$). If you draw it schematically, it is now clear that the union lies entirely to the left of the largest of the three values $k_1,k_2,k_3$. This indicates to you the general strategy, and the proof.

Denote for every $A_i$ an upper bound for it by $k_i$. Thus, $a\le k_i$ for all $a\in A_i$. Take $M$ to be the maximum among $\{k_1,\cdots, k_n\}$, thus $k_i\le M$ for all $1\le i\le n$. Now, it follows that $M$ is an upper bound of $\bigcup_{i}^nA_i$, since for every $a\in \bigcup_{i}^nA_i$ holds that $a\in A_i$  for some $1\le i\le n$, and thus that $a\in k_i\le M$, so $a\in M$.

Since the proof above only uses axioms of ordered fields, the general claim is proven. (You might want to figure out precisely which axiom is used where in the arguments above, to make sure you understand it).

Comment: @ Ittay. Could the above be explained in any concrete way.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As you can, for the practical purposes of the exercise, treat an ordered field as if it were the reals, this isn't very hard:

If $A_i$ is bounded to the right by some $k_i$, then for all $x \in A_i$ we have 
$$x \leq k_i. \quad (1)$$
Next, let 
$$k:= \max \{k_i \} , \quad (2)$$ 
and note that for any $x \in \cup A_i$, there is an $i$ such that 
$$x \in A_i. \quad (3)$$
Hence, you have

$$\begin{align}
x & \leq k_i \quad \text{ by (1) and (3)} \\
& \leq k \quad \text{ by (2)}\\ 
\end{align}$$

As $x$ was any element of $\cup A_i$, this was to be shown.

Comment: Is it possible to add any diagram or image to explain further.

Comment: @Avinesh: Yes. If you click 'edit' under your question, you go to an edit interface. On top of your text, you will see icons. If you hover over any icon, it will give you an explanation what it stands for. One of them is for attaching images. Once you click it, it should be self-explanatory.

Comment: @Avinesh: it appears I misunderstood your question - I thought you meant to post a pic illustrating a follow-up, but you asked if I could add an illustrating pic. I can't, at least not easily. Here's an analogy though: in each family of a friend there is a tallest person. If you choose the tallest among the tall, he will be larger than anyone in all the families of friends. That's really all this question is about.

Comment: That was a great explanation. Thank you so much i have understood the idea.